# Count Animation for number

Tags: winforms, animation

I want to create a countup/count down animation like [Countup.js](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/). Is this possible with label? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question shows lack of research effort and is too broad.

Comment: maybe the way I Phrased the question is bad. What i really want to do is implement easing in a number count. The counting part is a simple for loop what I want is to slow down the counting when its close to coming to the end of the loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of that concept using a form with two textboxes (start and end) a display label. As it gets closer to the end target, the ease gets higher and the process slows down.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cntr As Integer = CInt(Me.txtStart.Text)
    Dim ease As Integer = 0
    Do While cntr < Me.txtEnd.Text
        cntr += 1

        Me.lblCount.Text = cntr
        Me.lblCount.Refresh()

        Select Case Me.txtEnd.Text - cntr
            Case Is < 5
                ease = 100
            Case Is < 10
                ease = 40
            Case Is < 100
                ease = 10
            Case Is < 200
                ease = 1
        End Select

        If ease > 0 Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ease)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: was actually thinking about interpolation and all of that but this answer is simple and with a few tweaks it worked.

Comment: Sleeping on the UI thread.